# Gettig error PLS-00364

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure where I'm passing select statement to for loop and i'm using dynamic table which is passing at runtime and getting below error:

> LINE 23 PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid
>      LINE 19 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_TEST(TBL_NM IN VARCHAR2) 
IS

SRC_ID NUMBER(38);
SQL_Q VARCHAR2(250);
DEL_F VARCHAR2(250);

BEGIN 



    FOR I in (SELECT DEL_IND  FROM  TBL_NM) 
    LOOP
        SRC_ID := SRC_FILE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

        IF I.DEL_IND = 0
        THEN 
            execute immediate 'INSERT INTO TEST_HIST ' || ' (a,b,c,d,e,DEL_IND) ' ||
            ' SELECT a,b,c,d,e, '|| 0  || ' || ' FROM ' || TBL_NM;

        ELSIF I.DEL_IND = 1 
        THEN

            execute immediate 'INSERT INTO JESTX_IGNR ' || ' (a,b,c,d,e,DEL_IND,SRC_ID_NO) ' ||
            ' SELECT a,b,c,d,e, '|| 2 ||' , '|| SRC_ID || ' FROM ' || TBL_NM;

        END IF ;

     END LOOP;
     COMMIT;

END;
```

I call the procedure using:

```
EXEC CREATE_TEST('abc');
```

Comment: You have unbalanced single quotes in the first dynamic insert, but not sure what you want it to look like, since the second is wrong too - too many values...

Comment: Yes you are right..the second insert does have more values than the columns defined.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a REF CURSOR as you cannot use cursor for loop with dynamic sql.

I dont know the exact datatype for your column DEL_IND. Please declare accordingly.
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/procedures_plsql.htm#TDPNG60000) is some more information on Oracle REF CURSORS.

Try below

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_TEST(TBL_NM IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
TYPE c1ref is REF CURSOR;
SRC_ID NUMBER(38);
SQL_Q VARCHAR2(250);
DEL_F VARCHAR2(250);
DEL_IND NUMBER(5);
BEGIN 

    vsql_text := 'select DEL_IND from ' || TBL_NM;

    open c1ref for vsql_text;

    LOOP
        SRC_ID := SRC_FILE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
        fetch c1ref into DEL_IND;
         exit when c1ref%NOTFOUND;
        IF (DEL_IND = 0)
        THEN 
            execute immediate 'INSERT INTO TEST_HIST ' || ' (a,b,c,d,e,DEL_IND) ' ||
            ' SELECT a,b,c,d,e, '|| 0  || ' ||  FROM ' || TBL_NM;

        ELSIF (DEL_IND = 1) 
        THEN

            execute immediate 'INSERT INTO JESTX_IGNR ' || ' (a,b,c,d,e,DEL_IND) ' ||
            ' SELECT a,b,c,d,e, '|| 2 ||' , '|| SRC_ID || ' FROM ' || TBL_NM;

        END IF ;

     END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1ref;
   COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: I'm getting below error when i'm using above code LINE 17 PLS-00324: cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor 'CLREF'
LINE 17 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  LINE 16   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
LINE 16 PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name

Comment: i had it declared it as c1ref and not CLREF ..perhaps there is a typo ?

Comment: thanks i did one small change TYPE c1ref is REF CURSOR; to c1ref SYS_REFCURSOR; after that it is working,